# can't set alertdialog size

Tags: android, xml, size, android-alertdialog

I have the problem that my `alertdialog` has a fixed max size which is a perfect square with side length of `min(parent width, parent height)`. This creates the problem that I can't get the `alertdialog` to be wide screen.

In the dialog, I have loaded an `imageview` to show an image. I want this image to be shown wide screen and not in a square - which makes it smaller.

Code for the `alertDialog` in acivity:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.schematic_image_view, null);
alertadd.setView(view);
alertadd.show();
```

Code for the xml file `schematic_image_view.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <ImageView 
         android:id="@+id/schematic" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:src="@drawable/schematic">
    </ImageView>
```